# How to run .xcworkspace files

Tags: ios, xcode, github

I am trying to use this [project](https://github.com/Jawbone/spark-friends-ios) from git hub
and not sure how to run it on xcode.I am able to build it successfully but the simulator is not opening up.

i want it to run in the simulator.
Noted:
1.install cocoapods(done)

thanks for taking the time to go through my issue.

Comment: Which file you opened xcworkspace or xcodeproj ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please, check that you have selected Run target propertly (normally you Project name) in the top-left and not Pods target.
.xcworkspace can be executed as .xcodeproj